# Conditional operators error

Tags: c++, operators

I'm having trouble understanding why the following section of code is returning x and not b.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 12;
    int a = 1;
    int b = 0;

    cout << "answer: " << (x < a && 1 ? a : (x > b && 0 ? b : x)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My working is:

- x is NOT lower than a [logical and) 1, move to second set of brackets.
- x IS larger than both 0 [logival and] 0 there fore the result should be 'b'.

  (as both statement equate to true, shouldn't the Result_if_true statement be the output?)

Comment: `x > b && 0` means `(x > b) && (static_cast<bool>(0))`, not `(x > b) && (x > 0)`.

Comment: So because the bool value == 0, equating to false. 
Logical T and F = F therefore returning result_if_false?

Comment: Yes, that's about right.

Answer (score 1):

`x > b && 0` does **not** mean "x is larger than both b and 0".

Instead, it means: "x is larger than b, and 0 is a true statement". The `&&` operator is a logical AND that connects two statements. You cannot use it in the loose way in which the word "and" is used in natural language.

Answer (score 1):

```
(x < a && 1 ? a : (x > b && 0 ? b : x))
```

is parsed as

```
((x < a) && 1) ? a : (((x > b) && 0) ? b : x)
```

which is the same as

```
(false && true) ? a : ((true && false) ? b : x)
```

i.e.

```
false ? a : (false ? b : x)
```

i.e.

```
x
```

Answer (score 0):

In this expression

```
(x < a && 1 ? a : (x > b && 0 ? b : x))
```

there is at first evaluated condition

```
x < a && 1
```

It is equal to `false` because x is not less than a.

So the next expression that will be evaluated is

```
(x > b && 0 ? b : x)
```

In this expression condition

```
x > b && 0
```

is obviously equal to `false`

So the value of the whole expression will be the value of subexpression

```
x
```

and there will be outputed

```
answer: 12
```

Your logical mistake is that expression

```
x > b && 0
```

is not equivalent to

```
( x > b ) && ( x > 0 )
```

it is equivalent to

```
( x > b ) && ( 0 )
```

As expression

```
( 0 )
```

is equal to `false` then and

```
( x > b ) && ( 0 )
```

is equal to `false`